# React-Native LocalizedStrings.js - undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I'm starting to code in React-Native and, when trying to use the ReactLocalization library im getting the following error codes:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'localization.language')
<unknown>
    LocalizedStrings.js:17
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:122
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:65
_require
    require.js:49
<unknown>
    localizedStrings.js:3
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:122
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:65
_require
    require.js:49
<unknown>
    myWebView.js:25
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:122
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:65
_require
    require.js:49
<unknown>
    app.js:30
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:122
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:65
_require
    require.js:49
<unknown>
    index.js:15
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:122
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:65
_require
    require.js:49
<unknown>
    index.android.js:11
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:122
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:58
_require
    require.js:49
global code
    require-0.js:1
```

I've tried to research but as the framework is way new there is not a lot information around.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Here is the class code

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Simple module to localize the React interface using the same syntax
 * used in the ReactNativeLocalization module
 * (https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization)
 *
 * Originally developed by Stefano Falda (stefano.falda@gmail.com)
 *
 * It uses a call to the Navigator/Browser object to get the current interface language,
 * then display the correct language strings or the default language (the first
 * one if a match is not found).
 *
 * How to use:
 * Check the instructions at:
 * https://github.com/stefalda/react-localization
 */
export default class LocalizedStrings {

    _getBestMatchingLanguage(language, props) {
        //If an object with the passed language key exists return it
        if (props[language]) return language;
        //if the string is composed try to find a match with only the first language identifiers (en-US --> en)
        var idx = language.indexOf("-");
        if (idx >= 0) {
            language = language.substring(0, idx);
            if (props[language]) return language;
        }
        //Return the default language (the first coded)
        return Object.keys(props)[0];
    }


    constructor(props) {
        this.interfaceLanguage = (typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.languages && typeof navigator.languages !== 'undefined' && navigator.languages[0] && typeof navigator.languages[0] !== 'undefined') ? navigator.languages[0] :
            ((typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.language && typeof navigator.language !== 'undefined') ? navigator.language :
                ((typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.userLanguage && typeof navigator.userLanguage !== 'undefined') ? navigator.userLanguage :
                    'en-US'));
        //Store locally the passed strings
        this.props = props;
        this.defaultLanguage = Object.keys(props)[0];
        //Set language to its default value (the interface)
        this.setLanguage(this.interfaceLanguage);
    }

    //Can be used from ouside the class to force a particular language
    //independently from the interface one
    setLanguage(language) {
        //Check if a translation exists for the current language or if the default
        //should be used
        var bestLanguage = this._getBestMatchingLanguage(language, this.props);
        this.language = bestLanguage;
        //Associate the language object to the this object
        if (this.props[bestLanguage]) {
            //console.log("There are strings for the language:"+language);
            //Merge default 
            var localizedStrings = {...this.props[this.defaultLanguage], ...this.props[this.language] };
            for (var key in localizedStrings) {
                //console.log("Checking property:"+key);
                if (localizedStrings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    //console.log("Associating property:"+key);
                    this[key] = localizedStrings[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //The current language displayed (could differ from the interface language
    // if it has been forced manually and a matching translation has been found)
    getLanguage() {
        return this.language;
    }

    //The current interface language (could differ from the language displayed)
    getInterfaceLanguage() {
        return this.interfaceLanguage;
    }

    //Return an array containing the available languages passed as props in the constructor
    getAvailableLanguages() {
        if (!this.availableLanguages) {
            this.availableLanguages = [];
            for (let language in this.props) {
                this.availableLanguages.push(language);
            }
        }
        return this.availableLanguages;
    }

    //Format the passed string replacing the numbered placeholders
    //i.e. I'd like some {0} and {1}, or just {0}
    //Use example:
    //  strings.formatString(strings.question, strings.bread, strings.butter)
    formatString(str, ...values) {
        var res = str;
        for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            res = this._replaceAll("{" + i + "}", values[i], res);
        }
        return res;
    }

    //Return a string with the passed key in a different language 
    getString(key, language) {
        try {
            return this.props[language][key];
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log("No localization found for key " + key + " and language " + language);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Replace all occorrencies of a string in another using RegExp
    _replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
        //Escape find
        find = find.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
        return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the above code with this one:

https://github.com/stefalda/react-localization/blob/master/src/LocalizedStrings.js

and the error went away.